# optical flow: get fast motion with Farneback not possible?

Tags: python, algorithm, opencv, math, computer-vision

I think some of you know this function

```
flow = cv2.calcOpticalFlowFarneback(prvs,next, None, 0.5, 3, 15, 3, 5, 1.2, 0)
```

from OpenCV which uses the algorithm from Gunner Farneback to calculate the dense optical flow.

I have a question about this algorithm and I hope someone can give me an answer.

I can calculate the dense optical flow perfectly for smooth or slow motion in two pictures from a sequence.

Why does this not work for fast motion?
Does someone has an idea?
Can someone give me some points why this can't work?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

[`calcOpticalFlowFarneback`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html#cv2.calcOpticalFlowFarneback) function has two parameters related directly to the object displacement (faster movement results larger displacement)

1. level: according to original Gunner Farneback [paper](http://www.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:273847/FULLTEXT01.pdf):

> The problem of too large displacements can be reduced...Start
>   at a coarse scale to get a rough but reasonable displacement estimate and propagate this through finer scales to obtain increasingly more accurate estimates.
>   A drawback is that we need to recompute the polynomial expansion coefficients
>   for each scale, but this cost can be reduced by subsampling between scales.

2. winsize : averaging window size; larger values increase the algorithm robustness to image noise and give more chances for fast motion detection, but yield more blurred motion field.

So for faster movements these values should be optimized, but at the expense of performance and algorithm robustness.